# test file not found in Maxima

Tags: apt, software-installation

I installed [Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/index.html) via Terminal (`sudo-apt install maxima`) also its documentation (`sudo apt-install maxima-doc`) and when I open Maxima and try to run the test command:

```
run_testsuite(display_all=true);
```

it does nothing because an error break :
[image]

At the end in the error summary shows every tests is failed because an error break and

0 tests failed out of 0 total tests.
real time       :      0.449 secs

run-gbc time    :      0.140 secs

child run time  :      0.000 secs

gbc time        :      0.000 secs

(%o1)                                done

how can I fix this? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Maybe you need to install the `maxima-test` package as well?

Comment: I suggest you paste the messages you get instead of a screen capture. So others can copy-paste instead of typing.

Comment: @steeldriver I cannot believe it was so simple and evident, I was stuck in this issue grand part of the afternoon.  Please post the answer so I can check it.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio the screenshot was just for the output, all the input are typed in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test suite is packaged separately, as [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=maxima-test) `maxima-test`:

```
$ apt show maxima-test
Package: maxima-test
Version: 5.43.2-3
Priority: optional
Section: universe/math
Source: maxima
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Camm Maguire <camm@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 1955 kB
Depends: maxima (>= 5.43.2-3), maxima-src (>= 5.43.2-3), maxima-share (>= 5.43.2-3), tex-common (>= 6.13)
Download-Size: 320 kB
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
Description: Computer algebra system -- test suite
 Maxima is a fully symbolic computation program.  It is full featured
 doing symbolic manipulation of polynomials, matrices, rational
 functions, integration, Todd-coxeter methods for finite group
 analysis, graphing, multiple precision floating point computation.
 It has a symbolic source level debugger for maxima code.  Maxima is
 based on the original Macsyma developed at MIT in the 1970s.  It is
 quite reliable, and has good garbage collection, and no memory leaks.
 It comes with hundreds of self tests.
 .
 This package contains a build integrity test suite.
```